# Django csrf fails with jquery validate

Tags: jquery, django, validation, csrf

I encountered below issue working with JQuery form validation and Django inside modal even if I include the csrf token in the HTML template. If I submit the form without validating it with JQuery works just fine.

```
Forbidden (403)
CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.
```

On server side I use Django Form validation, nothing special.

Thank you in advance :)

Here is my code:

## html

```
<form class="form-inline" id="add-subtitle-modal" action="/add_subtitle/" role="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}

<div class="form-group">
      {{object.description}}
</div>

...

<button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">save</button>
```

## js

```
$('#add-subtitle-modal').validate({
        rules: {
...
}

etc

        submitHandler: function(form) {
            var $form = $(form);
            var $inputs = $form.find("input, select, button, textarea");
            $inputs.prop("disabled", true);

            //let the backend to manage submiting

            $form.submit();
        }
```

Comment: Sorry mate. I blindly assumed there was ajax involved, my bad. Regarding your problem, can you check, if the csrf token is sent together with all the POST input?

Comment: How I can do that? Because I can't print request.body as the server forbids it. In the view the csrf token it's rendered. :(

Comment: You can simply open chrome dev console and see what post data has been sent..

Comment: It is sent. I also added ctx.update(csrf(request)) in views.py and still forbids. Seems like a ghost :(

Comment: yes seems weird, can you maybe put the complete code somewhere on github?

Comment: Thank you for your intention, I skipped this till the end of the project and now I found the answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was my mistake. When I set the inputs as invalid before submission, the csrf was also set to disabled. Therefore, I think it wasn't submitted to the server. I think this was the issue as after I modified which field to become disabled it works.